# How to change the page title in image window popup in Zen Cart?

Tags: zen-cart

please help me to change the page title in image popup window. i'm using Zen cart.

Duplicate title affect the website SEO.

Please try to find out the good solution for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the includes/modules/meta_tags.php. you can change some of the following code:

```
  case 'popup_image':
   $meta_products_name = str_replace($bad_characters,'',zen_clean_html($products_values->fields['products_name']));
   define('META_TAG_TITLE', 'Image for ' . $meta_products_name);
```

`